# PAR : Explanation needed to create a PAR archive and use it remotely

Tags: perl, deployment, par

I would like to deploy my Perl application to several remote servers. My perl application consists of one big program, using non-core modules : Path::Iterator::Rule, XML::Writer, and two home-made modules.

I would like to be able to deploy my application on a remote server whithout having to copy one by one all of the modules my program uses, with all their dependencies.

I had a look at PAR, which could help with what I'd like to do. 
I need to create an archive ("modules.par") where I put my homemade modules, and I add Path::Iterator::Rule, XML::Writer modules ? But how can I be sure that all the dependencies of those modules are correctly added in my archive ?
I've understood that I need to do something like this in my main application :

```
use PAR;
use lib "modules.par";
use Path::Iterator::Rule;
use XML::Writer;
use HomemadeModule1;
use HomemadeModule2;
```

Sorry for the confusion, I'm really lost with all those module dependencies, ..

**Edit :**

So I've tried using cpanm -L extlib to create a directory with all my libraries, but I can't use cpanm on my system.
Now I'm trying to use PAR, I've created a file called "sources.par" in which all of my modules are contained, I used the following command :

```
pp -p myperlprogram.pl
```

This created the "sources.par", that I should be able to use in my program using this :

```
use PAR;
use lib "sources.par";
use XML::Writer;
use ..
```

But I still get the following message :

```
Can't locate XML/Writer.pm in @INC (@INC contains: sources.par CODE(0x10c0cc) /app/pro
dexpl/gld/LOA /usr/perl5/5.8.4/lib/sun4-solaris-64int /usr/perl5/5.8.4/lib /usr/
perl5/site_perl/5.8.4/sun4-solaris-64int /usr/perl5/site_perl/5.8.4 /usr/perl5/s
ite_perl /usr/perl5/vendor_perl/5.8.4/sun4-solaris-64int /usr/perl5/vendor_perl/
5.8.4 /usr/perl5/vendor_perl . CODE(0x10c1e0)) at /app/prodexpl/gld/LOA/AnalyseF
ichier.pm line 7.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at /app/prodexpl/gld/LOA/AnalyseFichier.pm lin
e 7.
Compilation failed in require at /app/prodexpl/gld/LOA/loganalysis.pl line 9.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at /app/prodexpl/gld/LOA/loganalysis.pl line 9
.
```

Any ideas what I could do ? You can see that @INC contains my sources.par file..

Comment: if you have PAR::Packer installed on your computer, you can then use (in a shell) `pp -o execname source_script.pl`. This will compile all your sources and dependencies to one executable archive. However, this doesn't fit all the needs an archive with a makefile.pl can cover.

Comment: @Ploutox I don't want to create an executable archive, as I will be deploying my app from a Linux computer to Windows or Linux computers..

Comment: Damn... I wouldn't know how to do it then ... [here](http://search.cpan.org/~rschupp/PAR-1.007/lib/PAR/Tutorial.pod) is some tutorial on `PAR`, if you haven't read it already

Comment: Well I read it and there is a part that says you can add the modules to a par archive, and then use them like I did with the piece of code I provided.

Comment: I updated my question with some information I gathered after I tried a few other things. Any ideas ?

Comment: Have you tried to write `use sources.par::XML::Writer;` ? Just a guess though

Comment: I get a "syntax error", I don't think you can put the name of a file before the use of a library.

Answer (score 0):

Create a package using either [`Module::Build`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Module%3a%3aBuild) or [`Module::Build::Tiny`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Module%3a%3aBuild%3a%3aTiny), and then just install the package on these remote machines.  That way you can just specify what the dependencies are, and [`cpanm`](https://metacpan.org/pod/distribution/App-cpanminus/bin/cpanm) can install them as well.

Comment: I'm not sure you've understood what I wanted to do.. I'd like to have a way to get all the modules my Perl application needs directly bundled with my Perl application on a remote computer where none of the modules are installed. I've had a look at Module::Build but it looks like it's meant for people who want to upload their modules, right ?